# I want to send notification to user whenever admin feed data firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, token

I want to make a system like if the user feed some data inside firebase the user should get notification

I have added notification node inside database and inside that there is one column for heading when admin write something in heading the user should get notification

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using your own server.
Like when admin push new data then it also call an api for server to let it lmow that data is updated then the server send a push notification to all users through firebase.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)  you automatically run backend code like sending notification  in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests